# Query non-partitioned column on Entire Hive external Table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, hiveql, dremio

I have hive external table (s3 files stored in parquet format) created with spark about 30 GB in size and with few hundreds of partitions. However I need to query the data on a non partition column (say SUPPLIER_ID) to see complete transaction history but not specific to a period or date (Partition columns). How can I ensure this query pattern where I am not sure which partition data belongs to on a Hive table?

Comment: just do not filter by partition and do not include partition in groupby

Comment: that would force entire table scan and its query might not even complete

Comment: Look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from: https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/cdh_ig_predicate_pushdown_parquet.html

> When filtering query results, a consumer of the parquet-mr API
> (for example, Hive or Spark) can fetch all records from the API and
> then evaluate each record against the predicates of the filtering
> condition. However, this requires assembling all records in memory,
> even non-matching ones. With predicate pushdown, these conditions are
> passed to the parquet-mr library instead, which evaluates the
> predicates on a lower level and discards non-matching records without
> assembling them first.
>
> For example, when evaluating the record {title: "The Starry Night",
> width: 92, height: 74} against the condition height > 80, it is not
> necessary to assemble the whole record, because it can be discarded
> solely based on its height attribute. However, while the condition
> height > width does not match the record either, predicate pushdown
> cannot be used in this case, because we need multiple fields of the
> same record to evaluate the predicate.
>
> Additionally, predicate pushdown also allows discarding whole row
> groups that cannot contain any matches based on their min/max
> statistics. For example, if the statistics of a row group include
> {min: 62, max: 78} for the height column and the filtering condition
> is height > 80, then none of the records in that row group can match,
> thus the whole row group can be discarded.

Just write a query and Parquet has a few smarts as listed above. It can skip various groups and uses columnar storage to check things, that is far faster than reading / deserializing the complete row.

Comment: thanks thebluephantom.  it sounds like having parquet files is enough for the situation. But i don't see better performance unless you include partition col in filter. Is there any benchmarks or references we can baseline volume of data vs expected query runtime

Comment: you would have to show query as i find it odd